# Removing alpha channels from grayscale images

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, scikit-image, grayscale

I have some B&W images, but in RGBa. I used skimage `rgb2gray(inp_image)` to convert them into grayscale. Yet they become grayscale images with alpha channel.

What do I do if I want to have those RGBa converted to grayscale without alpha channel?

Comment: you could firstly convert your RGBa image into RBG, then convert it into grayscale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this.

```
import cv2
  
image = cv2.imread('path to your image')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  
cv2.imshow('Gray image', gray)
  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**for multiple images**

```
import cv2
from os import listdir,makedirs
from os.path import isfile,join

source = r'path to source folder'
destination = r'path where you want to save'

files = [f for f in listdir(source) if isfile(join(source,f))] 

for image in files:
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(source,image))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        dstPath = join(destination,image)
        cv2.imwrite(destination,gray)
    except:
        print ("{} is not converted".format(image))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But are there any ways to save the images instead of having them displayed in new windows? And how to convert multiple images in the same folder at the same time? Sorry I am really not familiar with programming.

Comment: The image file is "grey"  and you can save it using `img.save('path where you want to save/gray.jpg', 'JPEG')` . For multiple images you can use a `for` loop

Comment: You're welcome. If you find this answer useful, please mark it as useful. That way the answer will be more priorities when someone else also have the same question.